# file upload with Reactjs and Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am trying to upload a file from frontend using reactjs. The backend is with Flask python. I am getting response code 400. What I am doing wrong?

frontend :

```
<input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChangeFile}/>
<button onClick={this.uploadFile}>
    Upload 
</Button>

uploadFile(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let f = this.state.fileToBeSent
    let f_name = this.state.fileToBeSent.name
    console.log(f_name)

    let fileReader = new  FileReader()
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f)
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {

      let toPost = {
        'file_name' : f_name,
        'file_data': e.target.result
      }
      console.log(toPost)
      return axios.post('/api/upload', toPost)
                  .then(res => console.log(res))
                  .catch(err => console.warn(err))
    }

  }
```

and on the backend :

```
@app.route('/api/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    print(file)
    return "done"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send your file instead.

**Example**

```js
uploadFile(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let file = this.state.fileToBeSent;
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("file", file);

  axios
    .post("/api/upload", formData)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err));
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Thanks it worked. I dont understand though why that code with filereader didnt work

Comment: @TheTechGuy Great! You're welcome. I don't have that much experience with Flask, but I think the way you do it in your question sends the data as JSON, so Flask doesn't recognize it as a file. You can open up the network tab in your browser and compare the headers/data sent.