# Error while uploading file from react to flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am trying to upload file using React and passing it to flask backend using post request. But i am getting error as `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)`.
I can't figure out the problem. If there is any other method possible, that also will be helpful.

This is upload.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';

class UploadVideo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imageURL: '',
    };

    this.handleUploadImage = this.handleUploadImage.bind(this);
  }

  handleUploadImage(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
        data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
        console.log(data)
        axios('/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleUploadImage}>
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }} type="file" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter the desired name of file" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn">Upload</button>
        </div>
        <img src={this.state.imageURL} alt="img" />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

This is index.py in flask:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def fileUpload():

   file = request.files['file'] 
   filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
   print(request.body, '1')
   return {"message":"Saved"}
```

Comment: can you share your localhost url for both react and flask apps

Comment: http://localhost:8000/upload. Its this

Comment: so react is running on localhost:3000?

Comment: Nope, react running on localhost:3500

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file upload with Reactjs and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132236/file-upload-with-reactjs-and-flask)

Answer (score 0):

since react and flask running in different port use full URL. check the code below

```
handleUploadImage(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
    console.log(data)
    axios('http://localhost:8000/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
}
```

Comment: It says url must start with leading slash

Comment: sorry, I thought I edited the react code, check the edit please

Comment: Now i get error as http://localhost:8000/upload 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: Open network console in your browser and check the exact error message you are getting from your flask app for the upload request.
Also check if the file object is being sent in the request body