# React Flask file upload

Tags: reactjs, flask, file-upload, frontend, backend

I'm trying to figure out how to upload a file with react as a frontend and flask as a backend.

I already have a react dragndrop feature, got it from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-drop-files

The react drag and drop part kinda looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FileUploader } from "react-drag-drop-files";

const fileTypes = ["JPG", "PNG", "GIF"];

function DragDrop() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = (file) => {
    setFile(file);
  };
  return (
    <FileUploader handleChange={handleChange} name="file" types={fileTypes} />
  );
}
```

export default DragDrop;

My flask file looks like this (basically almost empty):
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from distutils.log import debug
from fileinput import filename
from flask import *

```
import datetime


x = datetime.datetime.now()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello!'

# Route for seeing a data
@app.route('/data')
def get_time():
    return {}
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

I used this page on geeksforgeeks for that code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-file-in-python-flask/

Comment: I don't know what FileUploader is rendering in the dom, but I think you are missing an action button that will call the "/success" endpoint, like in the geeksgorgeeks example. Have you tried to implement these?

Comment: Related: [file upload with Reactjs and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132236/file-upload-with-reactjs-and-flask)